# Fastest way to count rows in array that match some condition in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

In Julia, I have an array of Booleans like this:

```
3×5 Array{Bool,2}:
  true  false  true  false   true
  true   true  true   true  false
 false  false  true   true  false
```

Except I have far more than three rows. What's the fastest/best way to count, say, the number of rows in which the second and fourth column are `true`, as well as the number of rows in which the second and third column are true? Right now I have something like this, where `N` is the number of rows:

```
num_2and3true = 0
num_2and4true = 0
for i = 1:N                                                                                                            
  if m[i,2] == 1                                                                                                        
    if m[i,3] == 1                                                                                                         
      num_2and3true += 1                                                                                                  
    end                                                                                                                  
    if m[i,4] == 1                                                                                                         
      num_2and4true += 1                                                                                                 
    end                                                                                                                
  end                                                                                                                
end
```

Is there a faster way to do this? I have a hunch that the way I'm doing it is too simple to be the best way. Thanks....

Comment: It is hard to say which algorithm will be faster. It depends heavily on your machine and the distribution of your values. In the end I hope julias compiler/analyzer will find the best version itself, since all infos are available in the code.

Comment: I'd bet you can improve performance on any of these answers by transposing the array and doing these operations on columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calculation in the question is indeed simple, and also pretty optimal. A slight improvement I've found is:

```
num_2and3true = 0
num_2and4true = 0
for i = indices(m,1)
    num_2and3true += Int(m[i,2] && m[i,3])
    num_2and4true += Int(m[i,2] && m[i,4])
end
```

It is about 20% faster on my machine. Probably because of reduced branching. To test I've used a random `m`, but results may vary for specific `m` (both size and content).

For better performance still, add before the `for` an `@inbounds`, which avoids some out of bounds error checking in array access:

```
@inbounds for i = indices(m,1)
```

and better still, add `@simd` too, to utilize when possible CPU support for SIMD instructions:

```
@inbounds @simd for i = indices(m,1)
```

Resulting in:

```
num_2and3true = 0
num_2and4true = 0
@inbounds @simd for i = indices(m,1)
    num_2and3true += Int(m[i,2] && m[i,3])
    num_2and4true += Int(m[i,2] && m[i,4])
end
```

which is 10x faster than version in question (again, on my machine).

UPDATE: See comment for reason `indices(m,1)` is better than `1:size(m,1)`.

UPDATE: Casting of Bool into 0/1 integers (thanks to a comment from DNF), makes the code even cleaner.

**Added another answer with a different approach (which is 3x faster)**. This answer is perhaps clearer though.

Comment: Thank you! It's nice and short. I figured that it was faster not to check m[i,2] twice but guess that isn't the case! What does the `@inbounds` do?

Comment: @BenS. Updated the answer with info about `@inbounds` and `@simd` addition.

Comment: A small comment, it is better to say `for i = indices(m,2)`, in that it also generalizes to non-1-based arrays: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/devdocs/offset-arrays#Using-indices-for-bounds-checks-and-loop-iteration-1

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Why `indices(m,2)`? We want to iterate over the rows.

Comment: yeah I misread the question - I actually wrote `indices(m,1)` first but then revisited the question and thought "no wait a minute he wants the 2 and 3 rows" and changed it :facepalm:

Comment: You can replace `ifelse(m[i,2] && m[i,3], 1, 0)` with just `m[i,2] && m[i,3]`. It's equally fast, but cleaner.

Comment: True, DNF. Now it's my turn to :facepalm:

Answer (score 3):

A faster but different approach is to use BitVectors which compress Bool Vectors and enable using single AND instructions to replace 64 logical AND operations. Of course, this comes at a cost of allocating some memory, but it turns out, the benefit outweighs the costs and it comes out faster (*caveat emptor*, on my machine). The function is:

```
function bar(m)
    num_2and3true = 0
    num_2and4true = 0
    v2 = BitVector(view(m,:,2))
    v3 = BitVector(view(m,:,3))
    v4 = BitVector(view(m,:,4))
    num_2and3true += sum(v2 .& v3)
    num_2and4true += sum(v2 .& v4)
    return (num_2and3true, num_2and4true)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get much speed-up from `simd`. This is the fastest version I found (actually, the `Int` makes a small difference):

```
function foo(m)
    n23 = n24 = 0
    @inbounds for i in indices(m, 1)
        !m[i, 2] && continue
        n23 += Int(m[i, 3])
        n24 += Int(m[i, 4])
    end
    return n23, n24
end
```

I tested this on `m = rand(Bool, 1000, 5)`. Note that you cannot use `@simd` here, because of the branch, but as I said, `@simd` does very little for me here.

The alternative is:

```
function bar(m)
    n23 = n24 = 0
    @inbounds @simd for i in indices(m, 1)
        n23 += Int(m[i, 2] && m[i, 3])
        n24 += Int(m[i, 2] && m[i, 4])
    end
    return n23, n24
end
```

**Edit:** I see one very strange thing: If I replace `!m[i, 2] && continue` with `m[i, 2] || continue` I see a 3x slowdown. What can be causing that?

Comment: Neat. I haven't used `continue` before...I am guessing that `!m[i, 2] && continue` means the same thing as `if !m[i, 2]; continue; end` but I don't see how, could you explain it?